# How to get the body of an answer using the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stackexchange-api

I am using [StackAPI](https://stackapps.com/questions/6841/stackapi-another-python-wrapper) to get the most voted questions and the most voted answers to those questions:-

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
SITE.max_pages=1
SITE.page_size=10

questions = SITE.fetch('questions', min=20, tagged='python', sort='votes')
for quest in questions['items']:
    if 'title' not in quest or quest['is_answered'] == False:
        continue
    title = quest['title']
    print('Question :- {0}'.format(title))
    question_id = quest['question_id']
    print('Question ID :- {0}'.format(question_id))
    top_answer = SITE.fetch('questions/' + str(question_id) + '/answers', order = 'desc', sort='votes')
    print('Most Voted Answer ID :- {0}'.format(top_answer['items'][0]['answer_id']))
```

Now using this `answer_id` I would like to get the body of that answer. 
I can get the rest of the details by using [this API link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to these posts on *Stack Apps*:

1. [Get questions with body and answers](https://stackapps.com/questions/4213/get-questions-with-body-and-answers)
2. [How to get Question/Answer body in the API response using filters?](https://stackapps.com/questions/3760/how-to-get-question-answer-body-in-the-api-response-using-filters)
3. [My filter is not returning any results. How to create a minimal filter?](https://stackapps.com/questions/7829/my-filter-is-not-returning-any-results-how-to-create-a-minimal-filter)

You need to use a [custom filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) to get question/answer/post bodies.

The good news is that you can also use the custom filter to get the answer data at the same time as you get the questions -- eliminating the need for later API calls.

For example, if you call the `/questions` route with the filter:
    `!*SU8CGYZitCB.D*(BDVIficKj7nFMLLDij64nVID)N9aK3GmR9kT4IzT*5iO_1y3iZ)6W.G*`

[You get results like](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&min=20&sort=votes&tagged=python&filter=!*SU8CGYZitCB.D*(BDVIficKj7nFMLLDij64nVID)N9aK3GmR9kT4IzT*5iO_1y3iZ)6W.G*&site=stackoverflow&run=true):

```js
"items": [ {
    "tags": ["python", "iterator", "generator", "yield", "coroutine"],
    "answers": [ {
        "owner": {"user_id": 8458, "display_name": "Douglas Mayle"},
        "is_accepted": false,
        "score": 248,
        "creation_date": 1224800643,
        "answer_id": 231778,
        "body": "<p><code>yield</code> is just like <code>return</code> - it returns what..."
        }, {
        "owner": {"user_id": 22656, "display_name": "Jon Skeet"},
        "is_accepted": false,
        "score": 139,
        "creation_date": 1224800766,
        "answer_id": 231788,
        "body": "<p>It's returning a generator. I'm not particularly familiar with Python, ..."
        }, {
        ...
    } ],
    "owner": {"user_id": 18300, "display_name": "Alex. S."},
    "is_answered": true,
    "accepted_answer_id": 231855,
    "answer_count": 40,
    "score": 8742,
    "creation_date": 1224800471,
    "question_id": 231767,
    "title": "What does the &quot;yield&quot; keyword do?"
    },
    ...
```

So, change this:

```
questions = SITE.fetch('questions', min=20, tagged='python', sort='votes')
```

To something like this:

```
questions = SITE.fetch('questions', min=20, tagged='python', sort='votes', filter='!*SU8CGYZitCB.D*(BDVIficKj7nFMLLDij64nVID)N9aK3GmR9kT4IzT*5iO_1y3iZ)6W.G*')
```

then adjust your `for` loop accordingly.